# How select first-child in this case?

Tags: html, css

I want to select p:first-child, but in this case as you can see

```
.root p:first-child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

selects all p tags in root not first child: id="this"

How to select only id="this" using .root p:first-child in this case or should I use id?

code :
https://codepen.io/qkreltms/pen/LYPLwPB

```css
.root p:first-child {
  background-color: green;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: inline-box
}

.root {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  display: block;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root" id="this">
  <div class="container">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>test2</p>
  </div>
    <div class="container">
    <p>test3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just change the CSS of the .root class like this: .root div:first-child p . It will work fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`first-child` selector select and style every element that is the first child of its parent. So here the styles were being applied to all `<p>` tags as there are only one `<p>` tag inside its respective parent `.container`

Instead of selecting `p`'s first-child, select `first-child` of the class  `.container` for getting the desired result.

```css
.root .container:first-child p{
  background-color: green;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: inline-box
}

.root {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  display: block;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="container">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>test2</p>
  </div>
    <div class="container">
    <p>test3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

with this css snippet:

```
.root p:first-child {
     background-color: green;
}
```

your are selecting every p elements that are first in their own parents.
change to this for first p elements inside first container:

```
.root .container:first-child p{
      background-color: green;
}
```

or this for first container and first p:

```
.root .container:first-child p:first-child{
      background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for ?
Selecting the paragraph in the first-child of the root element.

```css
.root .container:first-child p {
  background-color: green;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: inline-box
}

.root {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  display: block;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="container">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>test2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>test3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple way to select the first-child, it depend on your requirement following is few way to do that.

First if you want to select the first child of `container` then use below.

```css
.root .container p:first-child {
  background-color: green;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: inline-box
}

.root {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  display: block;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="container">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>test2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>test3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second if you want to select the first of child of first  `container` then use below.

```css
.root .container:first-child p {
  background-color: green;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: inline-box
}

.root {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  display: block;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="container">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>test2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>test3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```